# Display distinct users who booked event on the same day

Tags: mysql

I'm unsuccessfully writing a query that will work on these two tables

Events table :

```
+-----------------------------+
|id   | date       | time     |
+-----------------------------+
|1    | 2015.06.23 | 09:00:00 | 
|2    | 2015.06.23 | 09:00:00 |
|3    | 2015.06.23 | 09:00:00 |
|4    | 2015.06.23 | 13:00:00 |
+-----------------------------+
```

Users table (where i see who booked which event):

```
+--------------------------+
|object_id   | user_id     |
+--------------------------+
|1           | 12          | 
|1           | 10          |
|2           | 12          |
|2           | 9           |
|3           | 7           |
+--------------------------+
```

Users.object_id is Events.id

The query that I can't seem to write correctly needs to alert me if a user has booked more than 1 event that happen on the same day at the same time.

My query should (i guess) use a GROUP BY ... HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Users.user_id) > 1 but i can't get to write it correctly.

In the data displayed above the result should be:

User_id 12 because they booked events.id 1 and 2, and those events happen on the same day, same time.
Could you please help me getting there? Thank you. SB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT u.`user_id`
FROM `users` u
JOIN `events` e ON e.`id` = u.`object_id`
GROUP BY u.`user_id`, e.`date`, e.`time`
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Comment: thanks axxis. the request doesn't display the expected result... I'll keep working on it to try to adapt it...

Comment: it does. However it stops working correctly if I add values in users http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/97331/1

Comment: in the last fiddle it should answer 10 and 12 sqlfiddle.com/#!9/97331/1

Comment: @s_b Then the `GROUP BY` clause, also needs the `user_id` field. Check my updated answer.